# How to find the min and max in a number list

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, numbers

I'm having trouble with a project for class and I was looking for some help. I need to make a code where it will ask for numbers repeatedly and then print out the min and max in the list. My teacher said we can do this anyway we wish.

```
   num_list = []
   while True:
   num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
   if num == "done" : break
   if num >= 0:
   num_list.append(num)
   print min(num_list)
   print max(num_list)
```

This is what I have so far, it asks for the number inputs and will break when I enter done, but it will **only** print out "Done" for the min and max in the list.

Comment: Fix your indentation. It is impossible to know what is in or outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the numbers to an integer or float type before calling min/max.

```
# under n >= 0:
num = int(num) # or num = float(num)
num_list.append(num)
```

so an example of working code would be:

```
num_list = []
while True:
   num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
   if num == "done" :
       break
   try: # use a try except to verify user input is in fact a number
       num = int(num) + 0 # alternatively use float(num) if non integer numerical inputs will be used
       if num >= 0:
           num_list.append(num)
           print "min: ",min(num_list)
           print "max: ",max(num_list)
   except:
       print "invalid input"
```

Not calling max/min every iteration:

```
num_list = []
_min, _max = None, None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try: # use a try except to verify user input is in fact a number
        num = int(num) # alternatively use float(num) if non integer numerical inputs will be used
        if num >= 0:
            if not _min or not _max:
                _min,_max = num, num
            elif num < _min:
                _min = num
            elif num > _max:
                _max = num

            num_list.append(num)

   except:
       print "invalid input"

   print "min:", _min
   print "max:", _max
```

Comment: Why are you adding 0 and continually calling min and max?

Comment: I was adding 0 as a form a verification that num was in fact a numeric value, deleted that.  Used a _min, _max reference instead of calling the min/max function repeatedly, you're right thats far more efficient.

Comment: I meant more along the lines that the min and max should be printed when the loop ends